# gTTS.say(text) takes string

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, gtts

I am trying to create a website using Django which will take some text as input and convert it into audio.

I created an empty array that should store the value of the input and convert it into audio. But when I run the server, it gives me an error saying - **gTTS.say(text) takes string.**

My views.py

```
#An empty array called textForTts
textForTts = []

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    tts = forms.CharField(label = "Convert text to audio here")

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            tts = form.cleaned_data["tts"]
            textForTts.append(tts)

    obj = say(language='en-us', text= textForTts)
    return render(request,'demo/website.html',{
        "form" : UploadFileForm(),
        'obj':obj
    })
```

my index.html:

```
{% block body %}

{% load gTTS %}

    <form method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}


    <audio
    src = "{{obj}}"
    controls
    ></audio>


    {{form}}
    ​ <input type = "submit">

    </form>     

      
          {% endblock %}
```

This is my first time trying out Django. What should I do to fix my errors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use [Django-Gtts](https://pypi.org/project/Django-Gtts/), right? AFAIK, correct form to call `say` inside Django template is:

```
{% load gTTS %}

<audio
 src="{% say 'en-us' 'text to say' %}"
 controls
></audio>
```

I'd suggest to refactor your view as follows:

```
return render(request, "demo/website.html", {
    "form": UploadFileForm(),
    "lang": "en-us",
    "text": "text to say",
})
```

This will allow you to call say in Django template as follows:

```
{% load gTTS %}

<audio
 src="{% say lang text %}"
 controls
></audio>
```